# Using an expression pedal with a PC?

Tags: guitar, effects-pedal, pc

Currently I'm using my **guitar** through a **Ubisoft Rocksmith adapter**, and I'm thinking of buying an **expression pedal** with a **6.3 mm jack** output, but I don't know how could I connect it to my **PC** so I could use it in i.e. **Amplitube**.

Is the only solution to this is buying a **relatively big and expensive USB interface**?

**I want to use only this pedal. Is there a single adapter on the market?**

What other solutions are there?

Comment: You need something that turns analog expression pedal voltages into a digital signal that a computer can interpret. One of the most popular and easiest ways to do that is to get some kind of MIDI controller that has an expression pedal input.

Comment: @ToddWilcox could you recommend one which just has that one input?

Comment: I've found this https://beatbars.com/en/home.html , but it's a bit expensive for me.

Comment: This isn’t a site for product recommendations. Even if it were, I don’t know of much in the way of midi controllers for less than €50. You might look at a music instrument retailer web site and see what they have.

Answer (score 1):

USB instrument interfaces don't have to be large and expensive, there are small and inexpensive versions available.

If you want to use a standard effects pedal like a WAH then a simple USB interface will work.

The Behringer interface line starts at around $30 USD. You would send the guitar into the expression pedal, then into the interface.

If you want to control the software to use built-in expression, then you need to use a MIDI controller. There are a few different configurations available, but the most direct for what you describe would be an "Expression pedal to MIDI adapter" which starts around 50 Euro.

I have seen stand-alone MIDI expression pedals on the market before, but I believe the price range starts around $150 USD and goes up from there.